# Add button to dynamic html table javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to dynamic javascript and I'm adding a button to my dynamic HTML table.

```
function addToTable(){

    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var row = table.insertRow(counter + 1);

    var removeRow=document.createElement("BUTTON");

    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0)
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);

    cell0.innerHTML = counter + 1;
    cell1.innerHTML = getName(array[counter]); 
    cell2.innerHTML = getEmail(array[counter]);
    cell3.innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(removeRow);

    counter++;
}
```

Whenever I run this, in the first the cells I get the index number, the name, and the email. in the 4th cell it prints "[object HTMLButtonElement]".

And an addition issue is when I assign a label on the button the entire method doesn't work. This is how I was adding a label.

```
var removeRow=document.createElement("BUTTON");
var text=document.createTextNode("Remove");
btn.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(removeRow);
```

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code?

Comment: Regarding this line: `document.getElementById("table");` do you really have an element with `id="table"` in your HTML?

Comment: He probably does, because in his question he states that something other than what he expected is showing up inside the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting the innerHTML of the cell to the return value of `document.appendChild` this returns an DOM object which is turned into a string when set as HTML. You should simply append the button to the cell.

```
cell3.appendChild( removeRow );
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Spz/1/)

Note: as I did in the fiddle, you should set the innerHTML of the created button.